# How do I echo an expression with both single and double quotes?

Tags: shell, quoting, echo

I have tried many things, but I'm new to the shell. Is it possible to have both double and single quotes within an `echo`?

I want to generate `echo "scan 'LPV',{FILTER => "(PrefixFilter ('MP1-Eq1')"}"` for system call, but I am getting an error because of the mutiple double and single quotes.

```
ftable="echo" " \"" "scan" " " "'LPV',{FILTER => " "\"" "\(" "PrefixFilter ""\(""'MP1-Eq1'" "\)" "\"" "\}" "\" "    
echo "scan 'LPV',{FILTER => "(PrefixFilter ('MP1-Eq1')"}"
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

How can I write `scan 'LPV',{FILTER => "(PrefixFilter ('MP1-Eq1')"}`? The syntax is `hbase`'s and I can't change it...

**EDIT**

I want to call **echo** within **system call**.

```
ftable="echo "scan 'LPV',{FILTER => "(PrefixFilter ('MP1-Eq1')"}" "
system(ftable)
error
```

I have tried with $ but

```
ftable="echo $'scan" "\'" "LPV" "\'" ",{FILTER => " "\"" "(PrefixFilter (" "\'" "MP1-Eq1" "\'" ")" "\"" "}' '"
system(ftable)
error
```

Getting an error because of double quote.

Comment: What language is this `system()`?

Comment: basically i m calling within my awk script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `bash`:

```
echo $'scan \'LPV\',{FILTER => "(PrefixFilter (\'MP1-Eq1\')"}'
```

or

```
echo "scan 'LPV',{FILTER => \"(PrefixFilter ('MP1-Eq1')\"}'"
```

For longer strings this may be a more convinient alternative:

```
> cat <<EOT
scan 'LPV',{FILTER => "(PrefixFilter ('MP1-Eq1')"}
EOT
```

with `EOT` or `\EOT`, depending on whether parameter expansion and quote removal (backslash) are intended or not.

**Usage within `awk`**

Defining this string within `awk` would make everything even more complex. This should be done outside `awk` in the shell:

```
ftable=$'echo "scan \'LPV\',{FILTER => "(PrefixFilter (\'MP1-Eq1\')"}"'
# echo "$ftable"
awk -v ftable="$ftable" '... system(ftable); ...'
```

Comment: @huake i am unable to call this from system.

Comment: @Aashu I'm afraid I don't understand this remark.

Comment: actually i have some prameter which i am reading from file in awk and want to pass within this string,which i want to run on system(ftable).

Comment: @Aashu It seems to me that `awk` wasn't mentioned before... However, I have extended my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to escape double quote inside double quote:

```
$ ftable="echo \"scan 'LPV',{FILTER => \"(PrefixFilter ('MP1-Eq1')\"}\""
$ echo $ftable
echo "scan 'LPV',{FILTER => "(PrefixFilter ('MP1-Eq1')"}"
```